# Subshifts, not of finite type, of $A^G$, where $G$ is finitely generated: The forbidden patterns

Tags: group-theory, dynamical-systems, computer-science

Let $A$ be a finite set and $G$ be a finitely generated group. Consider a word metric on $G$ with respect to some finite generating set and for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $B_n$ denote the ball of radius $n$ around the unit with respect to this metric.

Now let $X\subseteq A^G$ be an infinite (closed) subshift of $A^G$ which is not of finite type. Let $\{F_1,F_2,F_3,\ldots\}$ be a minimal set of forbidden patterns for $X$ in the following way:

(1) Each $F_i$ is a forbidden pattern.

(2) These forbidden patterns collectively define $X$.

(3) Each $F_i$ is truly new in the sense that it does not contain as a subpattern some other $F_j$.

For each $k\in\mathbb{N}$ let $n_k$ be the minimal integer such that the domain of $F_k$ can be fit inside $B_{n_k}$, i.e. $F_k$ can be defined as an element of $A^{P_k}$, where $P_k\subseteq B_{n_k}$. Then $\{n_i: i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a (not necessarily strictly and after possible re-ordering) increasing infinite sequence of positive integers.

So let $m_1<m_2<m_3<\ldots$ be the corresponding stricly increasing sequence. My question is: what can we say about this sequence? Can it be e.g. syndetic? Or must it grow "very fast"?

EDIT: I've realized that there are some easy situations when the sequence as considered above doesn't grow fast at all. Consider a subshift $X\subseteq \{0,1\}^\mathbb{Z}$ consisting of the two constant functions and then all the functions $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \{0,1\}$ such that there is $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ so that $f(m)=i$, for all $m\leq n$, and $f(l)=1-i$, for all $l>n$, where $i\in\{0,1\}$. Then the forbidden patterns are of the form $100\cdots001$ and $011\cdots110$, where the middle intervals of $0$'s, resp. $1$'s are arbitrarily long. This subshift is countable, but can be made uncountable just by increasing the alphabet by an additional letter.

Comment: Please include some context, i.e. why do you want to know this? Also, what is a "subshift...of finite type"? Does $A$ live in some superset on which $G$ acts?

Comment: @user1729 These are all very standard notions that are also easy to find. I think that, considering the length of the question above, it wouldn't be appropriate to state all these definitions. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subshift_of_finite_type in the case when $G=\mathbb{Z}$.